# Most performant solution for multiple databases in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, mysqli

I have four databases with different tables, let's call the databases `admindata`, `userdata`, `pagedata` and `mediadata`.

At the moment I use one instance of mysqli for all databases:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
```

I keep this instance open until the end of the page load. I was not sure about the performance so I made databases switches like this when I had multiple queries in one script:

```
$mysqli->query('SELECT fields FROM database1.table1');
$mysqli->query('SELECT fields FROM database2.table2');
```

instead of:

```
$mysqli->select_db('database1');
$mysqli->query('SELECT fields FROM table1');
$mysqli->select_db('database2');
$mysqli->query('SELECT fields FROM table2');
```

What of those two is better in performance? Or is it even better to hold one instance of `mysqli` for every database like this:

```
$mysqli->query('SELECT fields FROM table1');
$mysqli2 = new mysqli(...);
$mysqli2->query('SELECT fields FROM table2');
```

---

**EDIT**:

On php.net someone wrote two years ago:

`In some situations its useful to use this function for changing databases in general. We've  tested it in production environment and it seams to be faster with switching databases than creating new connections.`

http://ch2.php.net/mysqli_select_db

It would be nice to hear more about it.

Comment: I doubt you'll see a significant change in performance between both methods, unless you had millions of records (and even then). Your first method is more flexible though, and uses less code. However, using two instances (`$mysqli` and `$mysqli2`) would probably only complicate things, assuming you're using `$mysqli` for DB connection purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

I was teached that is better to hold separate connection per database / per user. Not just because of matter of security, but also a flexibility of your code. In the future, if you would like to start using ORM, it will be very difficuilt to rewrite the code that uses single connection for several databases. It may also help with debugging the database problems.

On other hand there's potential problem of having many connections per request. In the project im leading, we do use separate connections, but we pay attention on closing them when they are not needed anymore.

I think there's no universal solution, and all depends from your own needs and requirements.